# <p> block with line break after each word and width limited to longest word

Tags: html, css

I want to have a `<p>` element with 1-3 words inside, so each new word will take a new line. Ideally, I want to make the `<p>` element as wide as the longest word. I cannot insert `<br>` or other `html`, as the data comes from a 3rd party api.

Right now the only way I found is to fix the `<p>` length, but with long words the result is rather ugly.

Any CSS alternative? Cheers!

```css
p {
  max-width: 48px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  word-break: break-all
}
```

```html
<p>extra super tag</p>
<p>extra tagverylong tag</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `width:min-content`

```css
p {
  width: min-content;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>extra super tag</p>
<p>extra tagverylong tag</p>
```

Another trick using `inline-block` for better support

```css
p {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main {
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>extra super tag</p>
  <p>extra tagverylong tag</p>
</div>
```

Also with `table`:

```css
p {
  display: table;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>extra super tag</p>
<p>extra tagverylong tag</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't even know that `width:min-content` existed. I mark this as correct

Answer (score 1):

Add

**`word-spacing: 100vw;`**

to your style.

```
p {
  max-width: 48px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  word-break: break-all
  word-spacing: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: That I wanted to avoid as it makes the background span the whole page, but thanks for the insight!